# mysql extract month from date format

Tags: mysql, datetime, datetime-format

My data value like below

```
          date_time
        ----------------        
        24:Sep:2016 22:19:35
        22:Oct:2016 22:19:35
        26:Sep:2016 22:19:35
        28:Sep:2016 22:19:35
```

Here I am using a query to check data where matched by month like below.

```
SELECT * FROM `audit_log` WHERE MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(date_time, '%d:%M:%Y %H:%i:%s')) ='Oct'
```

But this not working for me. But for year if I use that working

```
SELECT * FROM `audit_log` WHERE YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(date_time, '%d:%M:%Y %H:%i:%s')) ='2016'
```

Comment: Is the `date_time` column a DATETIME data type?

Comment: @RiggsFolly no it's just varchar type.

Comment: You should always store dates and times in DATE/TIME/DATATIME or TIMESTAMP data types, then this process is easy. If that column is some sort of text data type, its more difficult. Presentation should always be done in the presentation layer and not the database

Comment: Yeah I always did that. But this system already built here in database and some data inputed. So here my task is to fetch data. Is there any way to fetch data from this existing value?

Comment: You should rather use this : `MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(date_time, '%d:%M:%Y %H:%i:%s')) = 10`. But keep in mind what @RiggsFolly said. By the way,`MONTH(date) function returns the corresponding number of a month (1-12)`

Comment: @1000111 Thats what he used isnt it

Comment: If you look carefully he used `Month` function and tried to match with the first three chars of a month name. @RiggsFolly

Comment: `SELECT MONTH(STR_TO_DATE('24:Sep:2016 22:19:35', '%d:%M:%Y %H:%i:%s'))`

Will return 9 and not Oct

Comment: @1000111 I got it now, ta

Comment: ok i git it. i will search by month number. thanks @1000111

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got my answer.
I used long form month to search and in query used  `MONTHNAME`

```
SELECT * FROM `audit_log` WHERE MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(date_time, '%d:%M:%Y %H:%i:%s')) ='October'
```

in different process I can use `MONTH` though it's return number. I have to use month number to search in query. like bwlow

```
SELECT * FROM `audit_log` WHERE MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(date_time, '%d:%M:%Y %H:%i:%s')) ='10'
```